# Signal Hub Proxy Call back Receiving Pushed Object as Null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-2

The client side Proxy subscribed called back is receiving null when an object is passed. If a simple string is pushed from the server it is receiving perfectly on the client side as data parameter but not in case of an object . Not sure what I am missing need guidance & help.

Pushing msgdto object to connections in SignalR. C# code

```
chatHub.Clients.Clients(connectionIds).SubscribeToNewMessage(msgdto);
```

[image]

In browser the subscriber is receiving null .

My Signal R configuration are as follows

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
          ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
    }
}
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC & SignalR version 2.4.1 & signalr ReactJS lib for Client Side.